# Why does mongodb has list of identifiers instead of a single identifier?

Tags: mongodb

When I try to add a new document, why does mongodb generate an object of id as shown below rather than a single field? I thought id is just one unique value.

[image: Add new document]

Comment: Where do you see a list?

Comment: I have fixed the question, sorry about that. It shows as an inner object, I was expecting a single field value. Is that normal? Most tutorials I see seem to have just a single field value.

Comment: It is generating a property with datatype `ObjectId` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ - this is just how that is represented in some formats

Comment: It is a single value, it's just the way how the client displays it, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/#oid